# Error when using tensorflow HMC to marginalise GPR hyperparameters

Tags: tensorflow, gaussian-process

I originally posted on SO ([original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60063931/error-when-using-tensorflow-hmc-to-marginalise-gpr-hyperparameters)) but was suggested to post here.

I would like to use tensorflow (version 2) to use gaussian process regression to fit some data and I found the google colab example online here [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60063931/error-when-using-tensorflow-hmc-to-marginalise-gpr-hyperparameters). I have turned some of this notebook into a minimal example that is below.

Sometimes the code fails with the following error when using MCMC to marginalize the hyperparameters: and I was wondering if anyone has seen this before or knows how to get around this?

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Input matrix is not invertible.
     [[{{node mcmc_sample_chain/trace_scan/while/body/_168/smart_for_loop/while/body/_842/dual_averaging_step_size_adaptation___init__/_one_step/transformed_kernel_one_step/mh_one_step/hmc_kernel_one_step/leapfrog_integrate/while/body/_1244/leapfrog_integrate_one_step/maybe_call_fn_and_grads/value_and_gradients/value_and_gradient/gradients/leapfrog_integrate_one_step/maybe_call_fn_and_grads/value_and_gradients/value_and_gradient/PartitionedCall_grad/PartitionedCall/gradients/JointDistributionNamed/log_prob/JointDistributionNamed_log_prob_GaussianProcess/log_prob/JointDistributionNamed_log_prob_GaussianProcess/get_marginal_distribution/Cholesky_grad/MatrixTriangularSolve}}]] [Op:__inference_do_sampling_113645]

Function call stack:
do_sampling
```

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60063931/error-when-using-tensorflow-hmc-to-marginalise-gpr-hyperparameters) https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/probability/blob/master/tensorflow_probability/examples/jupyter_notebooks/Gaussian_Process_Regression_In_TFP.ipynb#scrollTo=jw-_1yC50xaM

Note that some of code below is a bit redundant but it should in some sections but it should be able to reproduce the error.

Thanks!

```
import time

import numpy as np
import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
tfb = tfp.bijectors
tfd = tfp.distributions
tfk = tfp.math.psd_kernels
tf.enable_v2_behavior()

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
#%pylab inline
# Configure plot defaults
plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor'] = 'white'
plt.rcParams['grid.color'] = '#666666'
#%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'png'

def sinusoid(x):
  return np.sin(3 * np.pi * x[..., 0])

def generate_1d_data(num_training_points, observation_noise_variance):
  """Generate noisy sinusoidal observations at a random set of points.

  Returns:
     observation_index_points, observations
  """
  index_points_ = np.random.uniform(-1., 1., (num_training_points, 1))
  index_points_ = index_points_.astype(np.float64)
  # y = f(x) + noise
  observations_ = (sinusoid(index_points_) +
                   np.random.normal(loc=0,
                                    scale=np.sqrt(observation_noise_variance),
                                    size=(num_training_points)))
  return index_points_, observations_

# Generate training data with a known noise level (we'll later try to recover
# this value from the data).
NUM_TRAINING_POINTS = 100
observation_index_points_, observations_ = generate_1d_data(
    num_training_points=NUM_TRAINING_POINTS,
    observation_noise_variance=.1)

def build_gp(amplitude, length_scale, observation_noise_variance):
  """Defines the conditional dist. of GP outputs, given kernel parameters."""

  # Create the covariance kernel, which will be shared between the prior (which we
  # use for maximum likelihood training) and the posterior (which we use for
  # posterior predictive sampling)
  kernel = tfk.ExponentiatedQuadratic(amplitude, length_scale)

  # Create the GP prior distribution, which we will use to train the model
  # parameters.
  return tfd.GaussianProcess(
      kernel=kernel,
      index_points=observation_index_points_,
      observation_noise_variance=observation_noise_variance)

gp_joint_model = tfd.JointDistributionNamed({
    'amplitude': tfd.LogNormal(loc=0., scale=np.float64(1.)),
    'length_scale': tfd.LogNormal(loc=0., scale=np.float64(1.)),
    'observation_noise_variance': tfd.LogNormal(loc=0., scale=np.float64(1.)),
    'observations': build_gp,
})

x = gp_joint_model.sample()
lp = gp_joint_model.log_prob(x)

print("sampled {}".format(x))
print("log_prob of sample: {}".format(lp))

# Create the trainable model parameters, which we'll subsequently optimize.
# Note that we constrain them to be strictly positive.

constrain_positive = tfb.Shift(np.finfo(np.float64).tiny)(tfb.Exp())

amplitude_var = tfp.util.TransformedVariable(
    initial_value=1.,
    bijector=constrain_positive,
    name='amplitude',
    dtype=np.float64)

length_scale_var = tfp.util.TransformedVariable(
    initial_value=1.,
    bijector=constrain_positive,
    name='length_scale',
    dtype=np.float64)

observation_noise_variance_var = tfp.util.TransformedVariable(
    initial_value=1.,
    bijector=constrain_positive,
    name='observation_noise_variance_var',
    dtype=np.float64)

trainable_variables = [v.trainable_variables[0] for v in 
                       [amplitude_var,
                       length_scale_var,
                       observation_noise_variance_var]]
# Use `tf.function` to trace the loss for more efficient evaluation.
@tf.function(autograph=False, experimental_compile=False)
def target_log_prob(amplitude, length_scale, observation_noise_variance):
  return gp_joint_model.log_prob({
      'amplitude': amplitude,
      'length_scale': length_scale,
      'observation_noise_variance': observation_noise_variance,
      'observations': observations_
  })

# Now we optimize the model parameters.
num_iters = 1000
optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=.01)

# Store the likelihood values during training, so we can plot the progress
lls_ = np.zeros(num_iters, np.float64)
for i in range(num_iters):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    loss = -target_log_prob(amplitude_var, length_scale_var,
                            observation_noise_variance_var)
  grads = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_variables)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, trainable_variables))
  lls_[i] = loss

print('Trained parameters:')
print('amplitude: {}'.format(amplitude_var._value().numpy()))
print('length_scale: {}'.format(length_scale_var._value().numpy()))
print('observation_noise_variance: {}'.format(observation_noise_variance_var._value().numpy()))


num_results = 100
num_burnin_steps = 50


sampler = tfp.mcmc.TransformedTransitionKernel(
    tfp.mcmc.HamiltonianMonteCarlo(
        target_log_prob_fn=target_log_prob,
        step_size=tf.cast(0.1, tf.float64),
        num_leapfrog_steps=8),
    bijector=[constrain_positive, constrain_positive, constrain_positive])

adaptive_sampler = tfp.mcmc.DualAveragingStepSizeAdaptation(
    inner_kernel=sampler,
    num_adaptation_steps=int(0.8 * num_burnin_steps),
    target_accept_prob=tf.cast(0.75, tf.float64))

initial_state = [tf.cast(x, tf.float64) for x in [1., 1., 1.]]

# Speed up sampling by tracing with `tf.function`.
@tf.function(autograph=False, experimental_compile=False)
def do_sampling():
    return tfp.mcmc.sample_chain(
      kernel=adaptive_sampler,
      current_state=initial_state,
      num_results=num_results,
      num_burnin_steps=num_burnin_steps,
      trace_fn=lambda current_state, kernel_results: kernel_results)

t0 = time.time()
samples, kernel_results = do_sampling()
t1 = time.time()
print("Inference ran in {:.2f}s.".format(t1-t0))
```